# Upload a file with google drive rest api

Tags: rest, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I am using a service account in google apps script so i can not use the normal google apps script api.

So i use the drive rest api for creating, moving, copy etc. but i am able to upload a file with the rest api. It uploads a file but it is without content or with wrong content.

This is my code:

```
var contentType = data.substring(5, data.indexOf(';')),
            bytes = Utilities.base64Decode(data.substr(data.indexOf('base64,') + 7)),
            blob = Utilities.newBlob(bytes, contentType, file);

  var service = getService();
if (service.hasAccess()) {
    var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=media';
    var data = {
        name: name,
        mimeType: "application/pdf",
        parents:  [parent]
    };
    var options = {
        method: 'post',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        body: blob ,
        payload: JSON.stringify(data),
        muteHttpExceptions: true,
        headers: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken()
        }
    };
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
   var result = JSON.stringify(response.getContentText());
   Logger.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
    return result["id"];
} else {
    Logger.log(service.getLastError());
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When uploading files using Drive API, you need to use the [files.create](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/create) method. You can see the javascript code reference in [Basic uploads](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads) where it is used. Also note that the [App Script uploading files](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive#uploading_files) uses the Drive v2 version of files.insert instead of files.create.